# Can a python object attribute return a function

Tags: python, oop

Is there a way to set a Python object attribute `object.attribute` to return a function or getter method?

For Example:

```
class CrossSection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])
```

Now constructing a Panel() Object, I would like to have an attribute Panel.data that returns data from the underlying CrossSection Objects each time (preferably without duplicating the data):

```
class Panel():
    def __init__(self):
        # - Core Object - #
        self.xs = dict()
        self.xs[1] = CrossSection()
        self.xs[2] = CrossSection()

        # - Data Object - #
        self.data = self.find_data()

    def find_data(self):
        self.data = dict()
        for n in self.xs.keys():
            self.data[n] = self.xs[n].data
        return self.data
```

In the example above, there are two issues:

1. the `find_data()` method runs only on `__init__` but if any of the underlying CrossSections() change (or are loaded after `__init__`) then self.data wouldn't represent the underlying `CrossSection()` objects.
2. `self.data` constructs a new dictionary.

However it does mimic the behaviour I would like:

```
p = Panel()
p.data

    {1: 0     1
1     3
2     5
3   NaN
4     6
5     8
dtype: float64,
 2: 0     1
1     3
2     5
3   NaN
4     6
5     8
dtype: float64}
```

Therefore,

1. Is there a way that I can request `Panel.data` such that it
   updates based on the underlying self.xs dictionary of
   `CrossSection()` objects.
2. Can `Panel.data` return a function over the underlying
   `CrossSection()` objects? [or is my only option to interface using
   class methods?]

Comment: a `dict` keyed by monotonically-increasing integers is a far more awkward data structure than a simple `list`.

Comment: Agreed - in my actual data they are referenced by a year integer and aren't always consecutive. I also store a year list for the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a Python object attribute object.attribute to return a function or getter method?

It's the typical use case of http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

> Can Panel.data return a function over the underlying CrossSection() objects?

Do you explicitly store the list of CrossSection() objects?

Comment: Yes I store the CrossSection() objects in a dictionary referenced by year. That looks like what I need - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!